# How do I make unique ID's on MySQL for different groups?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a form where theres eight input fields. Inside of the form I've seperated the eight input fields into so into two groups. Whenever I press the submit button I insert eight new rows into my SQL database.

How do I make it so that whenever I insert four new rows into my SQL database from the form, an ID (qid) is created for each four rows? For example, the first group of four input fields would have id 1, and the second one would have id 2, etc.

**My database**

tid
qid
aid (Primary key, auto increment)
answer
point

**Form**

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" class="copy" id="formid" name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Question 1

<br> 
Answer 1<input type="text" name="answer1"/> <select name="point1"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option></select><br>
Answer 2<input type="text" name="answer2"/> <select name="point2"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option></select><br>
Answer 3<input type="text" name="answer3"/> <select name="point3"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option></select><br>
Answer 4<input type="text" name="answer4"/> <select name="point4"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option></select>

Question 2 

<br> 
Answer 1<input type="text" name="answer1"/> <select name="point1"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option></select><br>
Answer 2<input type="text" name="answer2"/> <select name="point2"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option></select><br>
Answer 3 3<input type="text" name="answer3"/> <select name="point3"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option></select><br>
Answer 4<input type="text" name="answer4"/> <select name="point4"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option></select><br>

</form>
```

Process.php

```
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])){


$answer1=$_POST['answer1'];
$answer2=$_POST['answer2'];
$answer3=$_POST['answer3'];
$answer4=$_POST['answer4'];

$point1=$_POST['point1'];
$point2=$_POST['point2'];
$point3=$_POST['point3'];
$point4=$_POST['point4'];



$answer11=$_POST['answer11'];
$answer12=$_POST['answer12'];
$answer13=$_POST['answer13'];
$answer14=$_POST['answer14'];

$point11=$_POST['point11'];
$point12=$_POST['point12'];
$point13=$_POST['point13'];
$point14=$_POST['point14'];



$sql1= "INSERT INTO question (answer, point) VALUES ('$answer1', '$point1')";

$result=$connect->query($sql1);

$sql2= "INSERT INTO question (answer, point) VALUES ('$answer2', '$point2')";

$result=$connect->query($sql2);

$sql3= "INSERT INTO question (answer, point) VALUES ('$answer3', '$point3')";

$result=$connect->query($sql3);

$sql4= "INSERT INTO question (answer, point) VALUES ('$answer4', '$point4')";

$result=$connect->query($sql4);



$sql11= "INSERT INTO question (answer, point) VALUES ('$answer11', '$point11')";

$result=$connect->query($sql11);

$sql12= "INSERT INTO question (answer, point) VALUES ('$answer12', '$point12')";

$result=$connect->query($sql2);

$sql13= "INSERT INTO question (answer, point) VALUES ('$answer13', '$point13')";

$result=$connect->query($sql3);

$sql14= "INSERT INTO question (answer, point) VALUES ('$answer14', '$point14')";

$result=$connect->query($sql4);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you insert the first group, do a query first, like :

```
`select max(qid) from question`
```

you can store the result as variable `$qid`.

```
$qid ++; //plus one before insert to your database.
$sql1= "INSERT INTO question (answer, point, tid) VALUES ('$answer1', '$point1', '$qid')"; //your first group.
$sql2= "INSERT INTO question (answer, point, tid) VALUES ('$answer1', '$point1', '$qid')"; //your first group.
....//do them all.

$qid++; // plus one before insert the second group
$sql11= "INSERT INTO question (answer, point, tid) VALUES ('$answer1', '$point1', '$qid')"; //your second group.
$sql12= "INSERT INTO question (answer, point, tid) VALUES ('$answer1', '$point1', '$qid')"; //your second group.
....//do them all
```

Comment: I'm sorry, not good at PHP or SQL. Do I just write $qid + 1; And it'll work?

Comment: Thank you very much! @FisherMartyn! :)